# How can I display Samsung GT-S5660 current screen desktop to my HDMI TV screen?

Tags: hdmi, samsung-galaxy-gio, screen-sharing

I have pictures and videos with effects on my Samsung GT-S5660. How can I display those to my HDMI TV screen? The phone only has mini USB output.

Comment: Please try to use relevant tags. Applying 3 different phone tags (none of which was the phone you own) is confusing and defeats the purpose of tagging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to buy one of these [MHL to HDMI converters](http://www.amazon.ca/Samsung-SGH-i777-SGH-T989-SkyRocket-SGH-I717/dp/B006FYXL2O/ref=pd_cp_ce_2/181-2756464-3910106) - it mentions that it  specifically supports your device.

Comment: This is great, you are genius i am happy to get some hope at-least, i will buy and try and let the question be answered with some later follow up. thanks!